# How can I search for calendar events that are more than 1 year old on Outlook on the web (OWA)?

Tags: outlook-on-the-web, calendar

I want to look at some meeting info that occurred more than 1 year ago. I just know the email address of one of the participants of the meeting. Therefore, I go to https://outlook.office.com/calendar/view/week and search using that email address as the search query, but I don't see any calendar events older than 1 year:

[image]

How can I search for calendar events that are more than 1 year old on Outlook on the web (OWA)?